# Changing text color with respect to whats in the background with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, navbar

I want to use jquery to change the text color of my navbar whenever its in a section with black background. For example look at the following website linked at : [Fhoke](https://www.fhoke.com/) . As you can see when scrolling and reaching to the second section the text color changes to white. I want to do that.

Comment: just note down the position of div with black background, monitor scroll position and when it reaches black then change color attribute to white

Comment: Actually the div is in another page and I dont know how to check if the page is on home page or on another page.